# cvc-complex-type.2.2: Element 'location' must have no element [children]

Tags: java, web.xml, custom-error-pages

This error i got on web.xml file on my **error-page** tag:

> cvc-complex-type.2.2: Element 'location' must have no element
>   [children],

And my web.xml file looks like below (Not shown other tags) :

> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
>   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
>
> > ```
> > <error-page>
> >     <error-code>404</error-code>
> >     <location>/pages/error/404.jsp</location>
> > </error-page>
> >  </web-app>
> > ```

Answer (score 0):

FIX:

Those error-page tags are not supported in **Servlet 3.0**:

Changed Servlet version to : **version="2.5"** and schemaLocation to **web-app_2_5.xsd** in header of web.xml.